# How to call Navigator.pushNamed based on StreamProvider changes in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Lets say for example this is stream in `AuthenticationService`:
I simplified it with `bool`, usually the value will be wrapped with some immutable value object.

```
  BehaviorSubject<bool> _loggedIn$ = BehaviorSubject<bool>();
  BehaviorSubject<bool> get loggedIn$ => _loggedIn$;
```

And I mapped it as

```
  StreamProvider<bool>(
    builder: (context) =>
        Provider.of<AuthenticationService>(context, listen: false).loggedIn$,
  ),
```

And I use it in build function

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider.of<bool>(context)
        ? IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            onPressed: () => {Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RoutePath.Home)},
          )
        : IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () => {Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RoutePath.Login)},
          );
  }
```

So by now it works perfectly. If I put ticker to change the stream value every one second, the button magically changes.

One thing that I try to achieve right now, is make automatic routing when the value is `false` but i I try to call Navigator inside build function, I get Overlay error of trying to do something while `build` is being called.

What would be correct way of listening to a stream, and when the condition is set to push another route? 
And also to clean up the stream, so no dragging listeners are left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution for your specific use case would be to schedule the navigation for the next frame, so that it is not invoked synchronously and will therefore no longer throw that exception:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  ... invoke Navigator here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

is set a state variable when the value changes from true/false, the change in the state value will cause the widget to re-render and based on the state value navigate to a new route.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. The state changes, but can you show the code how to call the new route?